# Laravel9 Live Search ajax, how can I change the script when Im already have a value coded?

Tags: ajax, laravel

Trying to do use live search with value already coded in it
its already working when Im typing something but I want to do now is how can I use it without typing anything, just value that already input in the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#search').on('keyup',function()
    {
        $value=$(this).val();
        if($value){
            $('.alldata').hide();
            $('.searchdata').show();
        }
        else{
            $('.alldata').show();
            $('.searchdata').hide();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url:'{{URL::to('search')}}',
            data:{'search':$value},

            success:function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('#Content').html(data);
            }

        });
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a function and reuse it

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function search($value) {
        if($value){
            $('.alldata').hide();
            $('.searchdata').show();
        }
        else{
            $('.alldata').show();
            $('.searchdata').hide();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url:'{{URL::to('search')}}',
            data:{'search':$value},

            success:function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('#Content').html(data);
            }

        });
    }

    search($('#search').val())

    $('#search').on('keyup',function() {
        search($(this).val())
    })
</script>
```